# Background Image not showing in Spring MVC

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc

I am inserting a background image from a CSS property. I have also tried using `mvc:resources` mapping in spring-servlet.xml file, but it doesn't work.

JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login and Registration Form</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/user/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">

            <form class="register-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="User.name" /> <input type="password"
                    placeholder="Password" /> <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <button>Sign Up</button>
                <p class="message">
                    Have an account? <a href="#">Log in</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.6)),url(WEB-INF/css/images/bicycle1.png);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

spring-servlet.xml file:

```
    <context:annotation-config />

    <annotation-driven />
    <default-servlet-handler/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Error:

```
In browser console: bicycle1.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   bicycle1.png:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>YouServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.you.app.YouServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>YouServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Add the details of your web.xml

Comment: I had a problem and Tomcat didn't see the files. I had to add permission.

Comment: Add the css file in the folder Web Pages. where is the folder WEB-INF